# node-soap: "Non-whitespace before first tag."

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, sax

My WSDL is valid, but this error (in title) occurs on `soap.createClient`. The WSDL is hosted on the server. After inspecting the node-soap source, it looks like if I can disable the "strict" flag in the WSDL class this error will not occur, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable this. I tried passing options to the createClient method like so:

```
soap.createClient(wsdl, { strict: false }, callback);
```

But that does not seem to resolve this issue. Unfortunately I can't share the WSDL, but you can be sure that it passes validation, and there is no "non-whitespace" before the opening tag. I'm fairly certain that if I can somehow disable the strict option in the wsdl class that would resolve the issue. Has anyone had this occur before?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, it doesn't appear to be possible given the current code base.  I would suggest opening a [pull request](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/pulls) to add the functionality you need.

The code you've referenced above, `soap.createClient` ends up using the `wsdl.js` file which, when it parses the wsdl, ends up in a function `_parse`.  This function creates the sax parser but hard codes passing in `true` for the strict mode ([link to code](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/cb8d7a29636d2aba2381ca42976ff44cf79780be/lib/wsdl.js#L1497)):

```
p = sax.parser(true),
```

The soap module depends on the sax module, which takes in a boolean to determine if strict mode should be enabled ([link to code](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/51b27e7d326e0574584ae3e06b3616bcbaf889e5/lib/sax.js#L4)):

```
sax.parser = function (strict, opt) { return new SAXParser(strict, opt) }
```

So the options you pass to the `createClient` are not used in the creation of the sax parser, and instead it's set to strict mode.  However, like I said above, a pull request could fix this since it looks like the options are passed all the way to the creation of the WSDL object, so it'd just be a matter of creating the sax parser with that option passed, instead of `true`.

(Keep in mind the code additionally creates a sax parser within another function, `xmlToObject` ([link to source](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/cb8d7a29636d2aba2381ca42976ff44cf79780be/lib/wsdl.js#L1055)), but here again hard codes the strict mode)

Comment: Have you experienced the "Non-whitespace before first tag" error before? Is there a way I can resolve this by modifying my WSDL files? I don't see any "non-whitespace", and if I copy-paste the contents into any XML validators online the markup passes.

Comment: It looks like ([according to the code](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/51b27e7d326e0574584ae3e06b3616bcbaf889e5/lib/sax.js#L928-L939)) that the first character in the file is not `<` and not a "whitespace" character.  Could you confirm that?

Comment: No, even in vim after `:set list` shows no non-whitespace characters in between tags. The first line is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: I just created a file (`test.wsdl`) and put one line in it: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, then ran `soap.createClient("./test.wsdl", function(err, client) { console.log("done"); });` in the debugger, and saw it step through the whitespace error without any problems (and it output "done").  Can you try creating another WSDL file with that line in it and see if you can get anything to work?  I'm just unable to reproduce here.

Comment: I have an `if (err)` statement in the callback catching the error, I thought for a second that I could just ignore the error, but yeah I'll try that.

Comment: Managed to get past that error with the "test.wsdl", so I'm really unsure what's going on now.

Comment: Okay, got my fork loaded into my server, and am bypassing strict mode in sax - am now getting the following error: "Unexpected root element of WSDL or include". Will be looking into it

Comment: Okay I think the problem is that each part of the WSDL is prefixed with wsdl, so tags look like this: `<wsdl:definitions name="WhateverService">` or `<wsdl:operation name="WhateverOperation">`

Comment: There may be other problems with my WSDL. I can't post it up for public download, but it may have something to do with the import statements, which look like `<wsdl:types><xsd:schema><xsd:import schemaLocation="./path/to/file.xsd" namespace="uri" /></xsd:schema</wsdl:types>`